# Why is this get_pages returning an empty array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a meta box for my custom post type (which is inside a plugin).

I want to get all pages that are assigned a particular page template in my Wordpress site, so I use the following:

```
$surgeons = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'template-meet-the-team-single.php'
));
```

However, $surgeons is returned as an empty array, why?

It sounds like no page is using the template I'm stating, as if I just use the default `get_pages()` it returns all pages, but this is incorrect as I definitely have pages that are assigned this template.

Does it matter that this code is in a plugin file, and the `meta_value` is trying to locate this template in the plugin folder?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the right parameters in the array. The query itself looks okay so far. Could you try to declare the array before you use the `get_pages` method? You could see if there are any errors with that.

Comment: Have you at least one publish page using this template ?

Comment: @Bazaim Yes of course, I'm using the page template elsewhere in my site.

Comment: @creyD Do you mean literally stating `$surgeons = array();` ?

Comment: Nope, I suggested that you should declare the array as a variable and look if there ist the error. Then you could try to give this variable to the `get_pages` function. Would possibly help with debugging...

Comment: @creyD Sorry, I don't understand. Isn't that what I'm doing anyway, I'm giving the variable $surgeons to the get_pages function? and what I put in my comment surely is declaring the array as a variable?

Comment: If your template is in a folder in your theme, don't forget it in your meta_value (ex : 'meta_value' => 'myfolfer/template-meet-the-team-single.php')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't think this really provides an answer to the issue I Was having, this was the way to fix the array being returned and provide the correct results.

Instead of using `get_pages()`, I simply switched it to `get_posts()`, which then returned the correct results.

```
$surgeons = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'template-meet-the-team-single.php'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try by using custom query:

```
$all_team_single =  query_posts(array(
        'post_type' =>'page',
        'meta_key'  =>'_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value'=>'template-meet-the-team-single.php',
    ));
```

Your above code looking fine , to get more help please visit the below link. [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173469/loop-through-pages-with-specific-template](http://Click%20Here)

Comment: [Don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/69743)

Comment: Is any problem with using query_posts? Is any security issues.

Comment: It is explained in the answer linked in my comment.